# How do shadows work in THREE.js r75?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a tutorial for Three.js and in an example, it presents the concepts of shadows that can be utilized through methods such as: castShadow, receiveShadow and by setting shadowMapenabled to true.

However the example code is for Three.js r69. As of the date of this question, Three.js is at r75 and this code for casting shadows does not work.

Additionally the current Three.js documentation has no information on shadowMapenabled nor shadowMap.enabled or the other methods mentioned.

Suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the shadow map properties have been renamed in the recent versions, but they basically work the same.

Setting up the renderer for shadow maps (and choosing the more computational expensive shadow map type):

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // default THREE.PCFShadowMap
```

Setting up the light (notice how it also works with THREE.PointLight):

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 100 );
light.position.set( 0, 12, 0 );
light.castShadow = true;            // default false
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;  // default 512
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024; // default 512
light.shadow.camera.near = 2;       // default 0.5
light.shadow.camera.far = 100;      // default 500
//light.shadow.camera.left = 500    // Not sure about this one + 
                                    // right, top and bottom, Do they still do anything?
scene.add( light );
```

You get notified of all these API changes if you check your console when trying to use the properties specified in the current documention.

Creating you objects that casts and receives shadows is same as before:

```
//Creating box
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xdddddd, specular: 0x999999, shininess: 15, shading: THREE.FlatShading } );
var box = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, boxMaterial );
box.castShadow = true;
scene.add( box );

creating plane
var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20, 32, 32 );
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x00dddd, specular: 0x009900, shininess: 10, shading: THREE.FlatShading } )
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( plane );
```

Placing the plane under the box and it will receive a shadow.

Here is a working [codepen example](http://codepen.io/micnil/pen/ONZwbJ)

**EDIT**
In the current version of THREE.js, the scene needs to be rendered at least twice for the shadows to show.

THREE.js r75.

Comment: In that case, what's the bare minimum to get a basic shadow? Do I have to add shadowMap.type? Within my tutorial, the only console warning I received was to use "shadowMap.enabled" instead of "shadowMapEnabled". This is my code - http://codepen.io/estevancarlos/pen/pyVONK

Comment: @rpeg Ah, I think it is a bug in the current version of THREE.js. The first time the scene is rendered, the shadowmap will not show. you have to render it a second time. Just do: `renderer.render(scene, camera);` atleast twice. And you do not have to set `shadowMap.type`, `shadow.camera.near/far` or `shadow.mapSize.height/width`. All these have default values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a the simple code for shadow in three.js .Also included the shadow camera helper 
 `var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFAA55 );
    light.castShadow = true;
    light.position.set( 1, 3, 5 );
    light.shadowCameraNear = 0.5;
    scene.add( light );
    helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera );
        scene.add( helper );`

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/f17Lz5ux/5131/)